# Form API select list remove blank entry (default select an entry)

Tags: 7, forms

I populate an select list using the following code.

```
$getCompanies = 'SELECT nid, title FROM node where type = "my_type"';
        $companiesResult = db_query($getCompanies);
        $companyArray = array();
        $companyArray['empty'] = "";
        while ($data = db_fetch_object($companiesResult)) {
            $companyArray[$data->nid] = $data->title;
        }
        $form['company'] = array(
            '#title' => t('Type'),
            '#type' => 'select',
            '#description' => t(''),
            '#options' => $companyArray,
        );
    }
```

This gives me an empty result first. I want to remove this empty result. I tried adding #required by it does not add a default selection. What can I do to remove an empty element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The blank option was added by yourself:

```
$companyArray['empty'] = "";
```

If you remove that line you wont have a blank line, or alternatively your could change it to

```
$companyArray['empty'] = t("Please select");
```

To make the phrase *Please select* appear as default in the select option.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the property: `'#required' => TRUE` into `$form['company']`.

Comment: I did. It adds an * by the field but it does not remove the blank option.

Comment: Can you `dpm()` the array `$companyArray` ?

Comment: And also, what's the use of that line `$companyArray['empty'] = "";` ?